# What is this convention in method declaration?

Tags: objective-c, method-declaration

I have seen someone declaring a method in Objective C like this:

```
- (FMResultSet *)executeQueryWithFormat:(NSString*)format, ...;
```

Can anyone tell me what does the dotted notation at the end of the method declaration represent here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `...` represents a variable-length argument list, analogous to a variadic function in standard C. It indicates that the message can accept a variable number of arguments.

Within the message implementation variadic arguments are handled just the same way as in a standard C function, except in Objective-C the argument list is typically `nil` terminated. The same header file `stdarg.h` is used, and the same `va_list` type and associated macros for manipulating the list.

See this [OS X Developer document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html) for an example; and some standard C examples [here](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html).